# MySql access denied for every command

Tags: mysql, database, passwords, reset

I just installed mysql fresh on my computer. I never set any passwords nor have I set up any databases yet. Every command I try to enter into mysql is blocked because the system keeps prompting me for a password which I don't have. I've tried following many steps to reset the root password but often times when I enter a command such as:

```
./mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

My terminal says something along the lines of (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied).

So can anyone suggest some file I should check or some commands I should try to set/reset the password?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which steps you have taken this far based on your post, what OS you installed on (I am making an assumption it was on a linux distro), or whether it was from source or not but here are the steps you need to rest the root password:

```
How to reset the root password for mysql:
Stop mysql:
1. service mysql stop

Run mysql with skip grants to be able to login without any password
2. mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

Login as root
3. mysql -u root

4. mysql commands:
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("YourPWHere") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit

Stop mysql
5. service mysql stop

Start mysql normally:
6. service mysql start

Try to login using your new password:
7. mysql -u root -p
```

If that fails...I would just reinstall fresh...

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm working on OSX (El Capitan if it matters).

I tried step 2 and got this error along with a wall of other error text: /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld_safe.pid: Permission denied
awk: i/o error occurred while closing /dev/stdout

Comment: ughh...Mac worst environment for well anything except making pictures look better...give it a go anyways...If it doesnt work its a fresh install..try it again and set a root password when prompted through the install...

Comment: Okay, I'll give a reinstall a shot

Comment: Also, I was under the impression that mac was the preferred environment for web development in general, is this not the case?

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. To be fair my company isn't using mysql for their databases or anything. I'm just trying to quickly set up a mysql database because I want to test a JIRA plugin that won't run without it.

Comment: Okay I did a clean install and I realized I totally forgot about the temporary password it gave me before. This time though I have the temporary password and it still won't let me through when I use the command mysql -u root -p

Comment: are u sure you typed in the password when prompted correctly? n how come it did not prompt you for your own password during install...what is this temp PW stuff? I am not familiar with the install steps on a MAC but you should be prompted for a static root PW at some point...

Comment: Okay! It's up (phew). Now I'm getting: You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

Answer (score 0):

During my salary instalation you should enter a password at some stage so long think you must have left the default password which is root if this doesn't work Uninstaller and reinstall paying special attention to every step